# return two values from mysql with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Please tell me why when i used this part of code I can return result only of Select query but not Select2? Please

```
  con.ConnectionString = mysqlSB.ConnectionString;
                MySqlCommand Select = new MySqlCommand("select id from table1 where lang ='ua'", con);
                MySqlCommand Select2 = new MySqlCommand("select id from table2 where car='bmw'", con); 

                 MySqlDataReader myReader;
                 MySqlDataReader myReader2 ;

                con.Open();

                myReader = Select.ExecuteReader();
                myReader2 = Select2.ExecuteReader();

return (myReader2["id"].ToString());
```

Comment: Make a `struct` with two members and return an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two 'out' Parameters which you pass to your function and fill it with the results.

```
public void MyFunction(out string res1, out string res2){
....
res1 = select.toString();
....
}
```